# Cannot nest react navigation in component - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having trouble nesting a react-navigation StackNavigator within a component - as detailed here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-Component

However, even after following the guide to a T, I'm getting the following error -

> route 'Home' should declare a screen

Here is my "GoHome.js" component which, in reference to the guide on https://reactnavigation.org, is the "NavigatorWrappingScreen"

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import { Constants, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';
import MainNavigator from '../navigation/MainNavigator';
import AppInfo from '../components/AppInfo/AppInfo';
import { MainStyle } from '../stylesheets/MainStyle';


export default class GoHome extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  componentWillMount(){
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Error - location access denied');
    }else{
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      console.log(location);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image style = {MainStyle.imageContainer} source = {require('../assets/bg/bg_main.jpg')}>
        <AppInfo />
        <MainNavigator navigation = {this.props.navigation} />
      </Image>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

GoHome.router = MainNavigator.router;
```

And here is my MainNavigator.js component, which is the "MainScreenNavigator" component in the guide.

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Register from '../components/Register/Register';
import Password from '../components/Password/Password';
import AppInfo from '../components/AppInfo/AppInfo';
import { MainStyle } from '../stylesheets/MainStyle';
import GoHome from '../screens/GoHome';

const NavigatorMain  = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: GoHome
  },
  Register: {
    screen: Register
  },
  Password: {
    screen: Password
  }
});

// export default class MainNavigator extends Component {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <NavigatorMain />
//     );
//   }
// }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

export default NavigatorMain;
```

Any help AT ALL would be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: What is this: GoHome.router = MainNavigator.router; ?

Comment: Do you import MainNavigator into GoHome and at the same time import GoHome into MainNavigator or I misunderstand somethings?

Comment: Is NavigatorMain the same file as MainNavigator?

Comment: The GoHome.router = MainNavigator.router is supposed to make the GoHome component "Navigation aware" by assigning the MainNavigator's router to the GoHome router - as explained in the mentioned link.

Comment: Yes, the NavigatorMain is in the same file as MainNavigator - I've posted the code for the class here

Comment: And yes, I did import MainNavigator into GoHome and at the same time import GoHome into MainNavigator. I'm just doing what was explained in the guide, unless I misunderstood

Comment: Navigator is a separate file that consists of routeConfig: {Home: {screen: GoHome}} etc. and navigatorConfig {navigationOptions: {}, tabBarOptions: {}} etc. Screen should be either another navigator or a regular React.Component (a page that user sees). You should not import Navigator into React.Component.

Comment: Well, according to the official documents, as linked above, that is exactly what I am being told to do. Unless you have a different interpretation?

Comment: Please refer to these links, these will assist you to resolve the problem:
Please check these two articles, nesting drawer navigation has been explained elegantly. This will resolve your problem:

https://medium.com/@gsveitch/nested-navigators-need-new-i-ndices-f63eeb69c712

https://medium.com/@ivanzotov/react-native-deep-linking-with-authorization-screen-drawer-and-nested-navigators-in-react-4f702b1520a0